Error al guardar campos en modal (Modelo/Vista/Controlador)
Estoy añadiendo a la parte de previsualización de archivos mi aplicacion web (la cual está en un modal) la opción de añadir notas/anotaciones al documento, el fallo es que no se actualiza el valor de la nota, aunque este valor si llega al controlador, es el modelo el que no los recibe.
La app tiene dos previsualizadores, los del archivo dashboard.php que usan en el controlador su propia funcion de updateFiles() y en el modelo usan la función updateFiles(), en cambio en home.php el controlador usa updateFilesA() (Que es exactamente igual que la que usa dashboard.php) pero usa la misma función del modelo updateFiles() (la misma que usa el sistema de dashboard).
Llevo muy poco con esta aplicacion web que ya estaba hecha antes de incorporarme yo por si ven que no tengo mucha experiencia pido disculpas.
Si necesitan mas partes del código o información, no duden en pedirla.
EDIT: conseguí solucionar tanto la actualización de las notas y solucionar el bug de los estados (no estaba controlado anteriormente que si el documento no tenia estados, no se cargaba el campo estados en el  DOM y saltaba ese error y se usaba un ID erróneo en el elemento HTML).
Adjunto los códigos con la solución, la cual hasta que un compañero no la pruebe al 100% y me confirme no podre asegurar que es la solución definitiva
Home.php (contiene el html del campo y el script de la función de guardar cambios). El modal carga los datos del documento mediante los valores devueltos por la función $results
<!-- Más elementos del modal -->

<!-- NOTAS -->
<br>
<div class="row g-8 mb-8">
    <div class="accordion" id="kt_accordion_2">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="kt_accordion_2_header_1">
                <button id="btnAcordeon" class="accordion-button fs-4 fw-semibold" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#kt_accordion_2_body_1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="kt_accordion_2_body_1">
                    <label for="file_path" class="fs-6 form-label fw-bold text-dark"><?= lang('General.notes') ?></label>
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="kt_accordion_2_body_1" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="kt_accordion_2_header_1" data-bs-parent="#kt_accordion_2">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <textarea id="notes<?= $result['id'] ?>" name="notes" class="form-control" rows="4"><?= !empty($result['notes']) ? $result['notes'] : '' ?></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Más elementos del modal -->
    
<!-- Botón de "Guardar Cambios"-->  
<div class="row g-4 mb-8 mt-auto d-flex justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-xxl-7">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal"><?= lang('General.close') ?></button>
        <button onclick="saveChangess(<?= $result['id'] ?>)" value="<?= $result['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveChangesss"><?= lang('General.save') ?></button>
    </div>
</div>

</script>
function saveChangess(id) {
    var filename = 'file_name' + id;
    var filenameext = 'name_extension' + id;
    var filepath = 'file_path' + id;
    var notes = 'notes' + id;
    var new_status = 'statusField_' + id;
    var parametros = {
        "file_id": id,
        "file_name": document.getElementById(filename).value,
        "name_extension": document.getElementById(filenameext).value,
        "file_path": document.getElementById('file_path' + id).value,
        "new_status": document.getElementById(new_status) ? document.getElementById(new_status).value : '', // Verificar si el elemento existe
        "new_status": document.getElementById('status_file_' + id).value,
        "notes": document.getElementById(notes).value // Añadir el campo de notas
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: '<?= site_url('search/updateFileA') ?>', // Your controller's URL
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
        // Handle the response
        console.log(response);
        //alert('vuelve correcto de actualizar' + response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            // Handle the error        
        }
    });
    $('#kt_modal_' + id).modal('hide');
    location.reload();
}
</script>

SearchController.php
public function updateFileA()
{
    // Ensure the user is logged in.
    if (!$this->session->isLoggedIn) {
        return redirect()->to('login');
    }
    try{
        // Get POST data.
        $fileId = $this->request->getPost('file_id');
        $newFileName = $this->request->getPost('file_name');
        $newFileNameExt = $this->request->getPost('name_extension');
        $newFilePath = $this->request->getPost('file_path');
        $newStatus = $this->request->getPost('new_status');
        $notes = $this->request->getPost('notes'); // Obtener las notas     

        if ($newStatus <> "") {
            $newStatust = explode(",", $newStatus);
            $newStatus = $newStatust[0];
            if (isset($newStatust[1])) $_POST["order"] = $newStatust[1];
            if (isset($newStatust[2])) $_POST["firma"] = $newStatust[2];
        }
            
        // Registrar los datos recibidos
        file_put_contents('debug.log', 'Datos recibidos en updateFileA: ' . json_encode($_POST) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        // Create a new FilesModel instance.
        $extension = pathinfo($newFileNameExt, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $newFileNameWithExtension = "{$newFileName}.{$extension}";
        $model = new SearchModel();
        // get file data
        $file = $model->getFileData($fileId);

        // si no cambia nada
        if ($file['name'] == $newFileNameWithExtension && $file['path'] == $newFilePath and $file['status'] == $newStatus) {
            $response = [
                'status'   => 200,
                'error'    => null,
                'post'     => $_POST,
                'messages' => [
                    'success' => 'Data ready'
                ]
            ];
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        }

        // cuando cambia nombre de fichero, ver si versionar
        $extension = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $newFileNameWithExtension = "{$newFileName}.{$extension}";

        if ($file['name'] !== $newFileNameWithExtension) {
            $filenames = $model->getFileNames($newFileNameWithExtension);
            if (!empty($filenames)) {
                for ($x = 1001; $x <= 1999; $x++) {
                    $newFileNamev = $newFileName . '_' . substr(strval($x), 1);
                    $newFileNameWithExtension = "{$newFileNamev}.{$extension}";
                    $filenames = $model->getFileNames($newFileNameWithExtension);
                    if (empty($filenames)) break;
                }
                $newFileName = substr($newFileNameWithExtension, 0, strpos($newFileNameWithExtension, '.'));
            }
        }

        // Actualizar el archivo con las nuevas notas
        $updateResult = $model->updateFileA($fileId, $newFileName, $newFilePath, $newStatus, $notes);   
            
        // Registrar el resultado de la actualización
        file_put_contents('debug.log', 'Resultado de la actualización: ' . json_encode($updateResult) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        // Sign the pdf
        $Imagefirma = substr($this->session->userData['firma'], 7);
        if (isset($_POST["firma"]) && $_POST["firma"] == 1          && file_exists($Imagefirma)) {
            $firma = $this->session->userData['firma'];
            $file_path_name = '../../files/' . $newFilePath . '/' . $newFileName . '.pdf';
            $file_path_name1 = '../../files/' . $newFilePath . '/' . $newFileName . '.pdf1';
            copy($file_path_name, $file_path_name1);
            shell_exec("gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile='" . $file_path_name . "1' "  . "'" . $file_path_name . "'");

            require_once('fpdf.php');
            require_once('Fpdi/autoload.php');

            $pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();
            // set the source file

            //  $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("C:\\\\versalink.pdf");
            $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file_path_name1);
            for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
                $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);

                // add a page
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
                $x = 20;
                $y = 50;
                $width = 40; //$height=20;
                $Imagefirma = substr($this->session->userData['firma'], 7);
                $order = $_POST["order"];
                $positions = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
                $initialX = 2;
                $initialY = 280;
                $width = 40;
                $height = 20;

                if (in_array($order, $positions)) {
                    $x = $initialX + ($order - 2) * 40;
                    $y = $initialY;
                    $pdf->Image($Imagefirma, $x, $y, $width, $height);
                }
            }
            //$nuevoNombreDelPDF='C:\\\\versalinkfirmado12.pdf';
            unlink($file_path_name1);
            $nuevoNombreDelPDF = $file_path_name;
            $pdf->Output($nuevoNombreDelPDF, "F");
        }

        return $this->response->setJSON([
            'status' => 200,
            'message' => 'Cambios guardados correctamente',
            'data' => [
                //'file_id' => $fileId,
                //'file_name' => $newFileName,
                //'name_extension' => $newFileNameExt,
                //'file_path' => $newFilePath,
                'new_status' => $newStatus,
                'notes' => $notes,
                'debug' => $updateResult, // Incluir los datos de depuración en la respuesta
            ]
        ])->setStatusCode(200);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        log_message('error', 'Error en updateFileA: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return $this->response->setJSON([
            'status' => 500,
            'message' => 'Error al guardar los cambios'
        ]);
    }
}

SearchModel.php
public function updateFileA($fileId, $newFileName, $newFilePath, $newStatus, $notes)
{
    try 
    {
            
        // Registrar los datos que se van a actualizar
        file_put_contents('debug.log', 'Datos para actualizar en updateFileA: fileId=' . $fileId . ', newFileName=' . $newFileName . ', newFilePath=' . $newFilePath . ', newStatus=' . $newStatus . ', notes=' . $notes . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            
        $fileData = $this->find($fileId);

        if ($fileData) {
            $oldName = $fileData['name'];
            $oldPath = $fileData['path'];
            $extension = pathinfo($oldName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $data = [
                'status' => $newStatus,
                'notes' => $notes // Añadir el campo de notas
            ];

            // Registrar los datos para depuración
            file_put_contents('debug.log', 'Datos de depuración antes de la actualización: ' . json_encode($data) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
                
                $newFileNameWithExtension = "{$newFileName}.{$extension}";
                $oldFullPath = "../../files/{$oldPath}/{$oldName}";
                $newFullPath = "../../files/{$newFilePath}/{$newFileNameWithExtension}";
                $newDirPath = "../../files/{$newFilePath}";

                if (!file_exists($newDirPath)) {
                    if (!mkdir($newDirPath, 0777, true)) {
                        throw new \RuntimeException("Failed to create directory '{$newDirPath}'.");
                    }
                }

                if ($oldName !== $newFileNameWithExtension || $oldPath !== $newFilePath) {
                    if (rename($oldFullPath, $newFullPath)) {
                        $data['name'] = $newFileNameWithExtension;
                        $data['path'] = $newFilePath;
                        $this->update($fileId, $data);
                    } else {
                        throw new \RuntimeException("Failed to move file from '{$oldFullPath}' to '{$newFullPath}'.");
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->update($fileId, $data);
                }

            // Registrar el resultado de la actualización
            file_put_contents('debug.log', 'Archivo actualizado: ' . json_encode($data) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            return $data; // Devolver los datos de depuración
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       file_put_contents('debug.log', 'Error en updateFileA: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        throw $e;
    }
}

Muchisimas gracias!

No está demás decir que [phpmyadmin] nada tiene que ver con tu pregunta. Por otra parte: ¿verificaste que efectivamente existen los id a los que estás haciendo referencia en tu código? ¿Inspeccionaste el DOM?

Simplemente revisa el DOM, usando las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador, para verificar lo que se está creando. Para que document.getElementById('status_file_' + id).value funcione, debe haber en el DOM un elemento que tenga un id igual al valor status_file + el valor de la variable id.

pon el codigo del formulario, porque no veo ningun elemento con id 'file_name...'

@padaleiana al final vi que el error de Cannot read properties of null no tiene nada que ver con mi fallo de las notas, ese le solucionare despues, pero si, tiene toda la pinta de que hay algun ID con nombre distinto, editare la pregunta para que se centre en el apartado de notas

@A.Cedano al final vi que el error de Cannot read properties of null no tiene nada que ver con mi fallo de las notas, ese le solucionare despues, pero si, tiene toda la pinta de que hay algun ID con nombre distinto, editare la pregunta para que se centre en el apartado de notas

@clay al final vi que el error de Cannot read properties of null no tiene nada que ver con mi fallo de las notas, ese le solucionare despues, pero si, tiene toda la pinta de que hay algun ID con nombre distinto, editare la pregunta para que se centre en el apartado de notas

@padaleiana okey, lo he solucionado y me voy a volver loco, el campo de notas funcionaba desde el inicio, ha sido al comentar en home.php en la funcion saveChangess lo relacionado a new_status y ya funciona, el fallo era que no caia, y por eso disculpas por la inexperiencia, que el documento que estaba probando como no tiene estado, no genera el campo en el DOM y eso no estaba controlado por los anteriores desarrolladores, he añadido que si no lo encentra el estado pase como cadena vacia y ya funciona en los documentos sin estado.

@padaleiana Ahora pasa de que en los documentos con estado si actualizo la nota salta la respuesta de error de ajax pero se actualiza, pero si voy a actualizar el estado, salta el error y no se actualiza el estado. ¿cambio el post con el codigo nuevo y mas enfocado a este nuevo error o creo un nuevo post?

@A.Cedano en el ultimo comentario a padaleiana he hayado la solucion pero no al 100%

@clay en el ultimo comentario a padaleiana he hayado la solucion pero no al 100%

Dado que esta pregunta no tiene respuesta, creo que puedes [edit] focalizando el problema concreto y tratando de explicar el contexto. Evita poner en la pregunta código irrelevante. Si tienes un error de que no se encuentra un ID en el DOM, entonces tienes que poner el DOM (contenido HTML) que se está produciendo, para poder ayudarte a encontrar el problema. Si hiciera falta otro código (PHP) ya te lo diremos en comentarios. No hay que volverse loco, no estás ante un error demasiado complicado. Como dices, es por tu inexperiencia, pero la experiencia se adquiere equivocándose y corrigiendo.

@A.Cedano entre que he escrito el comentario anterior y este he solucionado los errores, ya se actualizan los estados y notas, tenga ese documento estados o no, de todas maneras estoy a la espera de que un compañero lo pruebe a fondo y me diga si ve algún bug o error, esperaré a ver que me dice y si encuentra algo reformulo la pregunta, mil gracias a todos por la ayuda

Ten muy presente que [es.so] no es un servicio de depuración de código. Se entiende que recién estés iniciando y que por lo tanto constantemente te equivoques (es completamente normal), pero la idea de preguntar en el sitio es exponer el caso, comentar el resultado esperado y el resultado obtenido, y un [repro] del problema en cuestión. Ahora mismo no se entiende cuál es la verdadera pregunta.

@padaleiana mildisculpas, la pregunta originalmente estaba relacionada a un fallo de que las notas que se introducian al documento no se actualizaban, he conseguido arreglarlo pero hasta que mi compañero no me confirme al 100x100 que funciona correctamente no puedo decir que está solucionado, vuelvo a disculparme si la pregunta es bastante liosa o a los nuevos lectores les va a causar confusión, si quieres editarla para evitar esa confusión puedes hacerlo sin problema
